# "Can you send me Fred and your flight information?"

Tags: possessives, compound-possessives, possessive-pronouns

This doesn't quite sound right but might be right. Consider

"Can you send me Fred and Amy's flight information?" This is correct via *The Chicago Manual of Style*.

Alternatively,

"Can you send me your and Fred's flight information?"

"Can you send me Fred's and your flight information?

or even
"Can you send me Fred and yours flight information?"

How about some help?

Comment: How would you like Fred packaged for shipment? And do you want him sent separately from my itinerary or together?

Comment: Be­cause the clitic apos­tro­phe-*s* style at­taches only to com­plete noun phrases not to per­sonal pro­nouns that al­ready have their own un­a­pos­tro­phized case in­flec­tions, no com­pound pos­ses­sive de­ter­min­ers us­ing pro­nouns in the first or sec­ond per­son that ev­ery­one is al­ways com­pletely com­fort­able with ex­ist in English. Please see the many an­swers in the linked du­pli­cates and re­lated ques­tions; if you feel that those **still** do not an­swer your ques­tion, then please edit your ques­tion to say why they did not do so, so that you can ask that it be re­öpened.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've read the "my wife's and my" answer before, too, but had no memory of it. Thus *Fred's and your* is the (arbitrary) standard

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what may be *technically* correct, if it doesn't sound right, then rephrase it:

> Can you send me the flight information for you and Fred?